# The header function is not working

Tags: php, if-statement, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I created a signup form and once a user has successfully signed up, it should redirect to home.php. But instead, it's being redirected to index.php. Everything else works (please see the code below). I could see that a user was added to my database, and that the status of the profile picture is 1.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submitSignup'])) {

include_once 'dbh.inc.php';

$first = $_POST['first'];
$last = $_POST['last'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['passwordS'];

if (empty($first) || empty($last) || empty($email) || empty($username) || empty($password)) {
    header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=empty"); exit();}
else{
    if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z\s'-]{2,50}$/", $first) || !preg_match("/^[A-Za-z\s'-]{2,50}$/", $last)) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=flnameinvalid&email=$email&username=$username"); exit();}
    else{
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=emailinvalid&first=$first&last=$last&username=$username"); exit();}
        else{
            $mysql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_username='$username';";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql);
            $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

            if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=unametaken&first=$first&last=$last&email=$email"); exit();}
            else{
                if (strlen($password) < 8) {
                    header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=strlen&first=$first&last=$last&email=$email&username=$username"); exit();}
                else{
                    if (!preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $password)) {
                        header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=num&first=$first&last=$last&email=$email&username=$username"); exit();}
                    else{
                        if (!preg_match("#[A-Z]+#", $password)) {
                            header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=cap&first=$first&last=$last&email=$email&username=$username"); exit();}
                        else{
                            $hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_first, user_last, user_email, user_username, user_password) 
                                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
                            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

                            if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare ($stmt, $sql)) {
                                echo "SQL error!";}
                            else{
                                mysqli_stmt_bind_param ($stmt, "sssss", $first, $last, $email, $username, $hashedPwd);
                                mysqli_stmt_execute ($stmt);



                                $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_username='$username' AND user_first='$first';";
                                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);

                                if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                        $userid = $row['id'];
                                        $sql4 = "INSERT INTO profileimg (userid, status) VALUES ($userid, 1);";
                                        mysqli_query($conn, $sql4);
                                    }
                                }
                                else{ echo "There are no users!";}
                            }
                            header("Location: ../home.php?signup=success"); exit();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}

else{header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=error");}
```

The header function doesn't work even if I placed it after the mysqli_execute($stmt).
I tried creating a user-defined function instead, but it is still not working. 
It was working last night when I haven't added the last if and else statement yet, the one with $sql3.

*========= UPDATED ==========*

Somehow, I was able to identify that the redirect it is following is the header function within the last else statement of my home.php. Here's the code

```
    <div class="sideright">
        <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $id = $row['id'];
                    $sqlImg = "SELECT * FROM profileimg where userid='$id'";
                    $resultImg = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlImg);
                    while ($rowImg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultImg)) {
                        echo "<div>";
                        if ($rowImg['status'] == 0) {
                            echo "<img src='uploads/profile".$id.".$fileActualExt'".mt_rand()." height='200' width='200'>";}
                        else{
                            echo "<img src='uploads/defaultprofilepicture.jpg' height='200' width='200'>";}
                        echo $row['user_username'];
                        echo "</div>";
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                echo "Sorry, an error occurred.";}


            if (isset($_SESSION['key'])) {
                echo 
                '<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="file" value="Change Profile Picture">
                <button type="submit" name="submitFile"> Go </button>
                </form>';
                echo 
                '<form action="includes/logout.inc.php" method="POST">
                <button type="submit" name="submitLogout"> Log Out </button>
                </form>';
            }
            else{
            header("Location: index.php");}
```

I still haven't fixed it, please help me find out where I went wrong.

Comment: is it still working if remove last if and else?

Comment: (Not the error but...) worth checking http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.insert-id.php to save having to do an extra query.

Comment: Instead of sending so many values through a redirect, you can store them in a session and redirect to the page without any parameters. Then unset those sessions after they have been put back into the form/displayed the message.

Comment: @BhumiShah, no, it is no longer working. Well I added some code to my other files as well. I updated my post, could you please check it out?

Comment: are you getting value in $_SESSION['key']?

Comment: I already fixed it! @BhumiShah, thanks a lot! Your questions gave me ideas of what to do next in order to fix it :)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">".
       "window.location='signup.php?signup=error';".
      "</script>";
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation of what your answer does and how it answers OP's question.

Comment: Why would you recommend using JavaScript redirects instead of sending a proper redirect from the server?

Comment: It works, but its not a good way of doing it. Fixing the program so that `header()` does the job is often much, much better.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this, it's Working for me.

**Replace** this code to Your **Header Location**

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    window.location.href='home.php';
</script>
```